# IPython Qt Console doesn't have a title in GNOME app switcher

Tags: arch-linux, gnome, python, gnome-shell

[image]

When I use the app switcher in GNOME 3.16, the IPython Qt Console (version 3.1.0) doesn't have a title under its icon (see image, and compare with Chromium). I also noticed that the icon doesn't have a title in the GNOME dock, nor is it present in the GNOME bar at the top.

I thought that maybe the title would be set in the `.desktop` file, but then I had a look at my `/usr/share/applications/ipython-qtconsole.desktop` and it doesn't look any different from other applications (i.e. it has a `Name` label set to an `IPython` value).

Is there a way to add a title manually?

I'm on Arch Linux using GNOME 3.16.1.

Comment: I'm not sure this is the case. But I have a similar problem with Mathematica. The `.desktop` file isn't actually what is handled by the Shell, but just a shortcut to call the real binary file: [screenshot](http://cl.ly/image/1Q340L0p3y3z).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a solution but I know where the problem comes from.
Gnome Shell uses the WM_CLASS property to associate apps to their ".desktop" files. [Reference](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeShell/ApplicationBased)

IPython Qtconsole's WM_CLASS value is empty and that is why you do not see any title up there. I reported an [upstream bug](https://github.com/jupyter/qtconsole/issues/11).

You could create a `.desktop` file without a name that would temporarily fix your problem but any other app with no WM_CLASS property would mapped to that one too.

```
cp /usr/share/applications/ipython-qtconsole.desktop .local/share/applications/.desktop
```

Comment: I see you already submitted a pull request as well? I manually applied the patch myself, and now I have indeed a title. Good work!

Comment: I'm glad that I could help. I use IPython a lot too and that bug was bothering me.

Comment: Maybe you could edit your patch in as well? Seeing that it's only a one-line edit to one file.

Answer (score 0):

This has never happened to me but this is more a "menu" issue than an application one.

As a starting point I suggest you navigate to the file

```
~/.config/menus/gnome-application.menu
```

See if its listed there and if there are any issues with the listing.

There is also an app called ["menulibre"](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/menulibre/) which allows you to add/modify icon names. It available in the AUR.

Comment: `~/.config/menus/gnome-application.menu` doesn't seem to exist. I've installed `menulibre` but that is just a front end for the `.desktop` files, right? I found nothing that would indicate it would hide its name from the dock, app switcher or top bar.

Comment: It's worth noting that `~/.config.menus` and `menulibre` are mostly deprecated in GNOME Shell. GNOME Shell just uses the info in the `.desktop` file and reads the category from `dconf`.